# Will an application run when only a newer framework is installed

Tags: c#, .net

I cannot seem to find an answer to my question, so I just ask it here:

Say, I have an application built for .Net framework 4.62.
Will it run on a server that only has 4.7 installed? 
(besides some older frameworks of course)

Or do I need to install every targeted framework?

Comment: Yes it will run. See [Installing the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - _"All of the .NET Framework versions listed in the following table [including 4.7] are in-place updates to the .NET Framework 4. In other words, if you install a later version, such as the .NET Framework 4.6, you do not first have to install the previous versions, such as the .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1, or 4.5.2."_

Comment: 4.7 is an in-place update to the 4.x line. You can't have multiple 4.x installations on the same machine.

Comment: You set the *minimum* required version in your project.  So yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The .NET Framework 4.5 and its point releases (4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, and 4.7) are backward-compatible with apps that were built with earlier versions of the .NET Framework. In other words, apps and components built with previous versions will work without modification on the .NET Framework 4.5.

For more info, you can refer to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx

In other words, it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

An application built for 4.6.2 will work on any platform with at least 4.6.2. installed, so 4.7 is okay too. Those versions are backwards compatible.

The above is true for all applications built for .NET 4.0 and higher. For some older versions (in the .NET 2-3.X era) you need to have installed a .NET Framework version up to 3.X, since that .NET Framework version still use the old .NET 2 CLR. From .NET 4 on, it is an in-place update.

Comment: For the term "will work", If I build on 4.7.2, will it be able to run on a 4.5.2 machine? I mean, will there only be possible runtime issue when you hit the new contents or the program won't even get allowed to start?

Comment: For what framework version did you build the code? @joe

Comment: I built on 4.7.2.

Comment: If you have built it *for* .NET 4.7.2., it will run on .NET 4.7.2 onwards. If you have built it on .NET 4.7.2. with the framework version set to 4.5, then it will run on 4.5 onwards.

Comment: I know this may sound weird because it's about forward compatibilities. But should I expect a runtime error or the .net won't even allow the program to start by indicating lack of components?

Comment: That is possible. Maybe the CLR will just throw when you hit incompatible parts in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, since the .net framework is backwards compatible.

See more info here:

[What is .NET framework backward compatibility?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149139/what-is-net-framework-backward-compatibility)