# Need help installing .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows Server 2016 Data Center for client requirement

Tags: .net, windows-server-2016

I have a requirement to run .NET Framework 4.5.2 (not anything higher ie. 4.6/7/8).  Per company policy I can not use anything other than Windows Server 2016 (DC in my case) yet no matter what I try the installer fails.  Does anyone have any guidance?

I have tried the offline installer for both .NET Framework 4.5.2 and the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack (KB2901951)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Does the installer fail with an error message?  Have you checked the installer's logs (I believe .NET usually creates a ton of them in `%TEMP%`, or maybe I'm thinking of Visual Studio)?  [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) would be an alternative, if not more appropriate, for this question.

Comment: Is there already another .NET Fw version installed on the server?

Comment: @Doc That was my original problem. I have since removed the .net version which comes by default on the OS (Ver 4.6).

Comment: @Bacon.  Yes there is a log.  The relevant error is:

 Installation failed with error code: (0x80240017)

Which, if my research thus far is accurate, appears to imply that the software is not intended for the OS I am trying to install it on.  There are however only 2 installers available and both fail with the same error.  I suspect the installation is only intended to work with Server 2012 R2 or lower.  If there is a work around great...if not am trying to find definitive proof that you can NOT install .net 4.5.2 on windows server 2016 datacenter.

Comment: What is the reason for the requirement of getting exactly 4.5.2 installed, and not a later one like 4.6, 4.7 or 4.8, which are a superset of 4.5.2? Some badly written software which checks precisels for "framework version =4.5.2"?

Comment: @Doc.  I suspect that is in fact the situation. My understanding is that there is a legacy application that requires 4.5.2 and there is no developer to support it.  The problem ofcourse being that our requirement to use the latest version on Windows Server means I am having issues getting older versions of .Net to work.

Comment: @LordBayne: you wrote " I suspect" - so you don't know? But you are aware that 4.5.2 applications should have no problems to run in an environment with a newer framework? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325509/will-an-application-run-when-only-a-newer-framework-is-installed  You will be better off clarifying if not a newer Fw version is fine your environment before you mix up Fw and OS versions which don't fit together.